# Python WebScrap from ASX API

Tags: web-scraping, stock

I found this site which allow me to scrap the announcement title and date. However, the amount of announcement is limited to 20. See image below, anyone know where I can scrap the title and date for each announcement for the fiscal year 2021

https://www.asx.com.au/asx/1/company/CBA/announcements?count=50&market_sensitive=false

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The API is limited to 20, it is an undocumented API, other than spending time working with the API to figure out other ways around it, they don't provide any other method of getting results outside the bounds of the 20 results.

If you want more, you're going to have to find another service, which likely involves paying or writing more code.